# permission denied for schema public at character 14

Tags: postgresql, laravel-9

I am using postgresql 15

and I tried running these

```
grant all privileges on database my_database to my_database_user;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to my_database_user;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema public to my_database_user;
grant all privileges on all functions in schema public to my_database_user;
```

but when I run

php artisan migrate --seed

I got

> SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied for schema public at character 14 (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not null, "migration" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null))

What I am missing?

I do make sure .env has correct credentials

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=my_database_user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Checking that i did

```
postgres=# \du my_database_user
            List of roles
  Role name  | Attributes | Member of 
-------------+------------+-----------
 my_database_user |            | {}
```

and

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_roles;
          rolname          | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrls | rolconfig |  oid  
---------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+-------
 my_database_user               | f        | t          | f             | f           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f            |           | 16389
```

Comment: Try to specify the owner of the database in the same way: ```ALTER DATABASE my_database OWNER TO my_database_user;```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are missing permissions on the schema:

```
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO my_database_user;
```

You are probably using PostgreSQL v15 or higher. The default permissions on the `public` schema have changed in v15. Before, the insecure default was to allow everyone (`PUBLIC`) to create objects in schema `public`. Now only the database owner can do that, unless you grant extra privileges.

Comment: I have tried this and I still get `error: create table "public"."strapi_migrations" ("id" serial primary key, "name" varchar(255), "time" timestamp) - permission denied for schema public`

Comment: @conor909 Then you either granted the permissions in the wrong database, or to the wrong user.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Laurenz's answer, this is for those who might be executing this from a script, as I was.

Since specifying the database in such a query is not possible (as a prefix, which I initially thought would be logical: `<db_name>.<schema_name>`), you first need to connect to the target database (with `\c <db_name>`), and then execute the query. If not, it will silently grant creation permission to whichever database context is connected (in my case, it was Postgres).